# -bash: Unset: command not found

Tags: bash, authentication, server, unset

When I log in to my remote server, using ssh, I got a message `-bash: Unset: command not found`.

You can find a sample screenshot
[image: here]

These are details of the server.

```
~$ lsb_release -a

LSB Version:    :base-4.0-amd64:base-4.0-noarch:core-4.0-amd64:core-4.0-noarch:graphics-4.0-amd64:graphics-4.0-noarch:printing-4.0-amd64:printing-4.0-noarch
Distributor ID: RedHatEnterpriseServer
Description:    Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.5 (Santiago)
Release:        6.5
Codename:       Santiago
```

Could you help me to fix this? You need to find where the server executing this wrong command (`Unset` instead of `unset`) after user login.

Solve:: **I found the error. In the file /etc/profile there was one Unset instead of unset**

Answer (score 0):

`Bash` is [case sensitive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Case_sensitivity), what you are trying to do is `unset` (note the lower u).

Comment: I do not type anything, After login to my server, it shows these error. I know the error is due to the case-sensitive fact. So, the server is executing a script which contains this `Unset` command. Where can I find this wrong command ??

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is you have edited the `.bashrc` file which resides in the home directory of the user.

instead of issuing the command `unset` you have issues `Unset`. This is the root cause of the issue.

Each time when a bash is initialized it will execute all the instructions in `.bashrc` file. That is why when you log in each time the error message is shown.

Comment: I did not edit the `.bashrc` file. This is occurring for every account in the server and also for the root.

Answer (score 0):

I found the error. In the file `/etc/profile` there was one `Unset` instead of `unset`.